Why is CUDA not included in LD_LIBRARY_PATH for GPU runtimes in Google Colab?
I am installing bitsandbytes on a Google Collab VM and it is not seeing the CUDA installation. I can see that CUDA is installed in the default directory, but I'm getting errors when trying to run the MiniGPT-4 demo related to the CUDA installation.
I can easily add the CUDA path with:
!export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64

But running it from Jupyter doesn't actually append the path. Running from the colab terminal does append the path. My question is: Why didn't bitsandbytes find the CUDA libraries, but also why can't I set system variables from the Jupyter notebook? Is this a compartmentalization issue?

I ran into this problem recently too.
I found there's two problem that should be solved.
First, when you use !export LD_LIBRARY_PATH directly on the Google Colab's cells, that usually doesn't directly impacted the environment. (I'm not sure why.) You could try using os.environ["PATH_NAME"] = PATH instead.
Secondly, it's usually caused by some versioning issues.
However, if your problem persists, you could try updating and reinstalling the cuda-toolkit, using the commands below:
!apt-get update
!apt-get install cuda-toolkit-11-8
import os
os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] += ":" + "/usr/local/cuda-11/lib64"
os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] += ":" + "/usr/local/cuda-11.8/lib64"

Here's the original source:
https://github.com/bitsandbytes-foundation/bitsandbytes/issues/950#issuecomment-1879907394
